# How do I write powershell output into specific columns repeatedly in a CSV file?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a Windows server for which I need to list the recursive folder paths of a given drive, and use that data to generate a CSV file that contains the following information:

**Hostname, FolderPath**

such that the desired outcome would look like this:

```
ServerName, G:\temp
ServerName, G:\temp\folderB
ServerName, G:\temp\folderB\folderC
ServerName, G:\temp\folder4\folder5\folder6
```

I am currently using the $env:computername environment variable to find the hostname of the server, and the following Powershell command to list the folders recursively:

```
Get-ChildItem G:\ -Name -Attributes D -Recurse
```

So far I've tested in my local command line with the following:

```
PS> $servername = $env:computername
PS> $list_folder = Get-ChildItem .\temp\ -Name -Attributes D -Recurse
PS> echo $servername > .\test.csv; $list_folder >> .\test.csv; echo '' >> .\test.csv
```

which generates output that looks like this (all in one column)

```
LOCAL_COMPUTERNAME
folder1
folderA
folder1\folder2
folder1\folder2\folder3
folderA\folderB
```

How would I write logic to place the given machine's hostname in column 1 of each line of the CSV file containing a new folder path, turning the above into something more like this:

```
LOCAL_COMPUTERNAME,folder1
LOCAL_COMPUTERNAME,folderA
LOCAL_COMPUTERNAME,folder1\folder2
LOCAL_COMPUTERNAME,folder1\folder2\folder3
LOCAL_COMPUTERNAME,folderA\folderB
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the server name and folder paths into variables and do this:

```
$object = New-Object psobject

$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Hostname'   -Value $SERVER_NAME
$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'FolderPath' -Value $FOLDER_PATH

$object | Export-Csv 'path to destination csv' -Notypeinformation
```

As per the changed question:

```
$list_folder = Get-ChildItem 'path' -Name -Attributes D -Recurse
$server_name = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$array = @()

foreach( $folder in $list_folder ) {
    $object = New-Object psobject
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Hostname'   -Value $server_name
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'FolderPath' -Value $folder
    $array += $object

}

$array | Export-Csv 'path' -Notypeinformation
```

Comment: Hey Vish, thank you for your quick reply.  Your code generates a CSV file with both columns correctly, but I'm still at a loss for how I would enter data into each line of that file, for both columns?  I re-edited my original post with more detail, I don't know if you saw it before your answer, but hopefully it clarifies what I'm attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Hey Vish,  Thanks!  That works perfectly -- I appreciate the quick response.  I'm still a little new with powershell, so I hadn't thought of instantiating an array and appending to it with each object.  

Thanks again!  You rock!